# Camel isMockEndpointsAndSkip doesn't skip jdbc endpoint

Tags: mocking, apache-camel, camel-jdbc

I have a route that end on a jdbc endpoint:

```
from(CONNECTOR).routeId(ROUTE_ID).process(createSelectStatement).to(jdbc);
```

The  jdbc Endpoint is created this way:

```
public static final String DB_NAME = "db";

private void setupJdbcEndpoint() {
    JdbcEndpoint endpoint = getContext().getEndpoint("jdbc:" + DB_NAME, JdbcEndpoint.class);
    endpoint.setOutputClass(OUTClass.class.getName());
    endpoint.setOutputType(JdbcOutputType.SelectList);
    jdbc = endpoint;
}
```

In my unit test i want "mock and skip" the database:

```
@Override
public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
    return "jdbc:*";
}
```

I also tried other patterns: "jdbc:db", "jdbc://db" (this string is shown in log and is the output of toString)

But no matter what pattern used the database is called. Log shows

```
org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer: Executing JDBC Statement: SELECT..
```

And the correct (empty) result is sent to mock endpoint at the end. And the mocked endpint `mock:jdbc:db` or `mock:jdbc://db` () never receives anything.

So how to skip this jdbc endpoint?

And how to get a reference to mock endpoints that are created with wildcards like '*'?

**EDIT**

With this setup i also see in log:

```
InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy: Adviced endpoint [jdbc://db] with mock endpoint [mock:jdbc:db]
```

So `isMockEndpointAndSkip` seems to work?! But in my case the jdbc endpoint is not skipped.

**2nd edit - tried answer from Vimsha**
Not using `isMockEndpointAndSkip` but providing an AdviceWithRouteBuilder didn't help (i think camel implements `isMockEndpointAndSkip` the same way). I see in log (using the builder Vimsha suggested):

```
InterceptSendToEndpoint[jdbc:* -> [To[mock://jdbc://db]]], process[Processor@0x6e9a5ed8], To[jdbc://db]]]
```

Besides that the database is still called the mock endpoint did not see any exchange.

here is the builder in detail:

```
new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                replaceFromWith(in);
                interceptSendToEndpoint("jdbc:*").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint().to(dbMock);

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimsha guided into right direction but for some reason this isn't working `interceptSendToEndpoint("jdbc:*").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()..`

But this works in my route i added an id to jdbc endpoint:

`...to(jdbc).id("jdbc")`

in test i added this AdviceWithRouteBuilder:

```
new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            replaceFromWith(in);
            // interceptSendToEndpoint("jdbc:*").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint().to(dbMock);
            weaveById("jdbcOut").replace().to(dbMock);
        }
    };
```

So `weaveById` and replace do the job.

Comment: This worked out for me as well. Just be sure that the id parameter in weaveById("...") matches with your endpoint's id.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an interceptor to skip sending to jdbc endpoint and sending it to a mock queue

```
RouteDefinition route = context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0);
route.adviceWith(context, new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint("jdbc:*")
                .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                .to("mock:jdbc");
        }
});
```

you can change your jdbc endpoint to this

```
private void setupJdbcEndpoint() {
    jdbc = "jdbc:" + DB_NAME + "?outputType=SelectList&outputClass=" + OUTClass.class.getName();
}
```

See this [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/JDBC)

Comment: thanks, i edited my post. At the moment i can't try your advice because of another problem.
and i dont like string based configuration at all - trying to keep out string literals.